# Does a fan or light on Shabbos need a Blech?

Tags: shabbat, derabanan

Obviously they wouldn't need a "blech" like we think of one, but would they need some sort of physical alteration to remind one not to adjust the knobs/switches on Shabbos?

More specifically, to leave a light or fan on on Shabbos, would one have to place a cover or piece of tape over the knobs and switches as a reminder? And if not, why not?

Comment: Depends on how likely you are to flip switches if you don't put this on.  My wife & I still tape some light switches that we know are likely to be flipped if not taped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue applies only where the chachamim were specifically concened.  One area of concern is performing acts which require seeing something well, like reading ([Shulcha Aruch O.C. 275](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=109)), where the chachamim were concerned we may inadvertently add oil to the wick to burn it brighter.  There is a machlokes brought in the Mishna Berurah whether a heker works.

We are lenient in this law, certainly when using non-adjustable lights, since  there is no gezeirah that one will come to light a lamp (probably because that takes more time and one will remember he may not do so).

As far as adjustable lights (dimmers) I don't know.

Fans do not fit into the reasoning, nor was there any such gezeirah.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  technically you would need to cover knobs and switches not as a reminder, but to prevent yourself from turning switches on and off...

check the shoulchan arouch shin yud chet.